# Have issues in reverse lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, windows-dns

I need assistance in a reverse lookup issue. I have a server say `XYZ.ABC.COM` having an IP `10.20.30.40`.  If I ping the server, it is resolving to the correct IP.

On reverse ping (i.e `ping -a 10.20.30.40`), it resolves to the domain name and not the server name

```
C:\bin>ping  -a 10.20.30.40

Pinging ABC [10.20.30.40] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.20.30.40: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=57
Reply from 10.20.30.40: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=57
Reply from 10.20.30.40: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=57
Reply from 10.20.30.40: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=57
```

On NBTSTAT -a 10.20.30.40, below are the results

```
       NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
ABC     <00>  GROUP       Registered
XYZ     <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
XYZ     <20>  UNIQUE      Registered

MAC Address = 00-15-5D-A6-88-05
```

As far as I know the `Nbtstat -a 10.20.30.40` should be as below

```
       NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
XYZ     <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
ABC     <00>  GROUP       Registered
XYZ     <20>  UNIQUE      Registered

MAC Address = 00-15-5D-A6-88-05
```

Kindly help me in fixing this issue and want to resolve the correct server name XYZ on reverse ping

Comment: You need to use the nslookup command instead of nbtstat. Offhand, I'd say there's something wonky with your reverse DNS tables - look in the 30.20.10.in-addr.arpa table, the 40 address should be a PTR to "xyz.abc.com.".

Comment: Why are you using NETBIOS?  Don't do that; it's not the 90's anymore.

Comment: I could not find any PTR record for this entry in DNS.

Answer (score 1):

`nbstat` is not a reverse [DNS] lookup.  [`nbstat` uses NETBIOS name resolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940106.aspx), which you really shouldn't be using for anything anyway.  If at all possible, disable NETBIOS entirely, and use DNS instead.

The command you're looking for to do a reverse DNS lookup is `nslookup 10.20.30.40`, not `nbstat`.

In any event, in a Windows environment, when an IP resolves to the domain rather than a server, you're looking at a Domain Controller, and that's expected behavior.  If the server isn't actually a Domain Controller, then you should take a look at your reverse DNS entries (PTR records), which you can find under `Reverse Lookup Zones` <kbd>--></kbd>  `30.20.10.in-addr.arpa` in the DNS Manager.  You can just change the PTR to the correct value, or delete both the forward and reverse entries and recreate them, if you prefer.

Comment: I could not find any PTR record in DNS nslookup

Comment: @RoshanRaikar  Then add one.  Not sure why it's a big deal for you (doubt it'd be worth my time), but it's not hard to add a reverse DNS entry either.  Just select the desired zone, right click, and it's pretty self explanatory from there.

Comment: If it was a question of a few entries, I would have done that.. I have around 400+ servers having this issues..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your reverse DNS tables have the entries, PTR addresses are not all automatically created.

Comment: could not find PTR record